# Appending a empty list when true with 1 and with zero according to data in pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame,Series
import numpy as np
titanic=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/prasun.j/Downloads/train.csv')
sex=[]
if titanic['Sex']=='male':
    sex.append(1)
else:
    sex.append(0)
sex
```

I m trying to a list which should be append by 1 when if statement encounters male or 0 when it encounters female,I dont know what I m doing wrong,can someone helpout,thanks in advance,execution throws following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-265768ba34be> in <module>()
      4 titanic=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/prasun.j/Downloads/train.csv')
      5 sex=[]
----> 6 if titanic['Sex']=='male':
      7     sex.append(1)
      8 else:

C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in __nonzero__(self)
   1119         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1120                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1121                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1122 
   1123     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 2):

When you check **`if titanic['Sex']=='male'`**, you are comparing `male` to the entire Series, which is why you get your **`ValueError`**.

If you really wanted to continue with an iterative approach, you could use **`iterrows`**, and check your condition for each row.  However, you should avoid iteration with Pandas, and here there is a much cleaner solution.

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sex': ['male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female']})
```

Just use **`np.where`** here:

```
np.where(df.sex == 'male', 1, 0)
# array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0])
```

You could also use boolean indexing:

```
(df.sex == 'male').astype(int).values.tolist()
# [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `get_dummies` dropping the first column(in this case dropping `female`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sex': ['male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female','male'], 'age':[10,20,30,40,50,60]})
```

use `pd.get_dummies` to obtain your values:

```
sex = pd.get_dummies(df['sex'],drop_first=True)
sex
   male
0  1
1  0
2  1
3  1
4  0
5  1
```

And then convert to a list:

```
list_sex = sex['male'].tolist()
list_sex

[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```